# Xamarin.Forms Editor equal character space

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

The first part of the image is the Xamarin.Forms Editor (running the UWP project). The second part is the Notepad app from Windows. Both have the same text, 10 times the letter "i" and 10 times the letter "o".

**Is there a way to make the Editor to allocate equal space for every character like the Notepad does?** I can't find any suitable property for this on the Editor control.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Use a mono-spaced font, just like Notepad does in your screenshot.

None of the controls have this feature built in to provide equal spacing for arbitrary fonts. Hence, the need to use a mono-spaced font.